# Debian VPS, no loop devices present, modprobe fails

Tags: virtualization, modprobe, loop-device

After acquiring a new virtual Debian squeeze I ran into a problem regarding loop devices.
My plan was to set up an encrypted FS in a regular file and mount it. Unfortunately I can't do that since there are no loop devices in /dev. mount tells me to run modprobe loop, but modprobe fails with

> FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-vserver-amd64/modules.dep:
>   No such file or directory

/lib/modules is empty. Still, the loop module seems to be loaded according to lsmod, so I created an /etc/modprobe.conf containing

> options loop max_loop=8

and restarted the server. Still nothing.

I tried to google every part of the problem, but no site seems to have something on this particular problem. Any ideas?

Comment: [It seems rather non-trivial, judging from this](http://linux-vserver.org/Loop_Device#Setting_up_a_loop-AES_loopback) (i.e. it needs patching) -- no idea how recent/still-needed this howto is, though

Comment: your VPS host probably doesn't want you to use loop devices?